# An error in Pyomo with a parameter represented as a matrix

Tags: pyomo

I am really new at pyomo and I have been trying to model a simple problem (I reduced the problem to the maximum so that I can see the error). Now the error is at the beginning when I declare the parameters as you will see below. I also use this matrix in my constraint with indexes `[i,j]`, and also an index error as in the figure below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your entire code? You probably index model.routing with only one index somewhere in your objective function or constraint(s) formulation.

Comment: Thank you for your response , i added a figure below to show how the routing matrix is used

Comment: See this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75450292/how-to-declare-params-in-pyomo/75450601#75450601

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the initialization of the parameters.
so for every parameter that should iterate, we use a function that returns each element of this parameter (with the correct index), as shown in the below:

```
def W_init(model, i, j):
    return matrix [i,j]

model.rout = Param(model.i, model.j,  initialize=W_init,mutable=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix as defined isn't a matrix (2-D); its just 1-D with value of $a$. To make 2-D you'll need np.ones(shape=(3,3)) or np.zeros((3,3)) to make a default matrix.

Comment: How do you know that $a$ is a scalar value (I don’t see it in the code snippet)?

Comment: I tried your proposition, but it ends with the same error :/

Comment: @Meriem could you print model.routing and see how it looks

Comment: @Meriem try without using the initialize. It will still create routing like a matrix.

Comment: @Meriem Check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897212/initializing-params-in-different-ways-gives-me-the-same-attribute-error

Comment: Ok! let me look at it !  thank you @Sutanu